# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #whitelist_end option[value*= + value + ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error, but mainly because of my own not knowing how to write it.

I have tried, but I have become really stuck. Whilst I feel I am close.

My code is the following :

```
function hourselect_link_field(source_select, target_select){
    var source_value = $('#' + source_select + ' :selected').val();
    var time = parseInt(source_value.replace(":", ""));


    var time_values = $("#" + target_select + " option").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();


    $.each(time_values, function (index, value) {
        var set_time = parseInt(value.replace(":", ""));
        if (set_time <= time) {
            $("#" + target_select + " option[value*=  + value + ]").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#" + target_select + " option[value*=  + value + ]").addClass('disabled');

        }
    });

//    console.log('time values = ' + time_values);

    //alert(time);
}
```

And my problem basically lies

```
$("#" + target_select + " option[value*=  + value + ]").prop('disabled', true);
$("#" + target_select + " option[value*=  + value + ]").addClass('disabled');
```

And to be even more specific :

```
option[value*=  + value + ]"
```

I seem not to be able to get the right syntax for this.

I want if value has : '00:00' that this should be set as disabled.
But it isn't working.

I get this syntax error

When trying :

```
        $("#" + target_select + " option[value*= " + value + "]").prop('disabled', true);
```

It also doesn't work.

So what am I missing?

> **Edit : Answer**
>
> The solution as provided by @Casper & @Bilal Siddiqui
>
> ```
> $.each(time_values, function (index, value) {
>     var set_time = parseInt(value.replace(":", ""));
>     if (set_time <= time) {
>         $(`#${target_select} option[value*='${value}']`).prop('disabled', true);
>         $("#" + target_select + " option[value*='" + value + "']").prop('disabled', true);
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: You seem to have two issues - which is causing the problem?  Trying to parse to `00:00` or setting it as disabled?   `$("#" + target_select + " option[value*=" + value + "]").prop('disabled', true);` should be fine (try without the space after the `=`) - but it "won't work" if it doesn't get that far.  So please determine exactly where the problem is and narrow the question to that issue.

Comment: Try this $(`#${target_select} option[value*='${value}']`).prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Can you create a complete [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Including the html and the *minimum* code required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: So you just needed to remove the space after `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use old method or ES6 template literals.

```js
let select1 = 'sel1';
let select2 = 'sel2';
let val = '00:00';

$(`#${select1} option[value*='${val}']`).prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
$("#" + select2 + " option[value*='" + val + "']").prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1">
  <option value="10">00:10</option>  
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>  
</select>
  
<select id="sel2">
   <option value="10">00:10</option>  
   <option value="00:00">00:00</option>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to try String Literals:

```
$(`#${target_select} option[value*='${value}']`).prop('disabled', true);
$(`#${target_select} option[value*='${value}']`).addClass('disabled');
```

**Another approach**

```
$("#" + target_select + " option").each(function () {
    var set_time = parseInt(this.value.replace(":", ""));
    if (set_time <= time) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: I presume you mean instead of $(`#${target_select} ` => ' (or) ". But both gives me another syntax error.

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #${target_select} option[value*=${value}] jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:13061

Feeling pretty dumb right now. Sorry.

Comment: Also, I have added another approach so that you may avoid using map and loop both.

Comment: I did but it is indeed the ` ones. But for some reason these refuse the work. I still don't know why.

            $(`#${target_select} option[value*='${value}']`).prop('disabled', true);

This works though

Comment: backtick is supported with ES6.